# SQL data not inside csv file when zip in php

Tags: php, sql, zip

I have a piece of codes which is exporting csv and few image files inside a zip file, The csv and images were zipped and exported in a zip file successfully. However, my SQL data did not populate the csv file. Only a empty blank sheet in the csv file. what am i doing wrong?

```
if($_GET['exportdata'] == 'true'){

    $datefrom = $_GET['datefrom'];
    $dateto = $_GET['dateto'];

    $filename = "data.csv"; // Create file name


    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');


        $fields = array('Sample No.',
            'Wet Density Mg/m3');

        fputcsv($f, $fields);

    $query = "SELECT [SampleNo], [Density]
              FROM EXPORT_DREDGER WHERE [Date] between ? and ?";

    $params = array($datefrom, $dateto);
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn2, $query, $params);

    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)){

            $row[0]; 
            $row[1];    

        fputcsv($f, $row);      
    }

    //move back to beginning of file
    fseek($f, 0);

   //export image and csv files as zip file

        $files = array('trip_image/A2002175102616/A2002175102616_img_0001.jpg', 'trip_image/A2002175102617/A2002175102617_img_0001.jpg', $filename);
        $zipname = 'file.zip';
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
        foreach ($files as $file) {
          $zip->addFile($file, basename($file));
        }
        $zip->close();


        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname.'.zip');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));

        readfile($zipname); 

        fpassthru($f);

 }
```